Question about Evans’ derivation of a Green's function
At page 34 of "Partial Differential Equations" by Evans, in order to define the Green function for the set $U$, the author defines a family of functions as the solutions of the boundary problem
\begin{cases}
\Delta \phi^x = 0 \quad \text{on} \: U\\
\phi^x = \Phi(x-y) \quad \text{on} \: \partial U
\end{cases}
where $U$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $\Phi$ is the fundamental solution to Laplace's equation.
However at no point I've seen a proof for the existence of a solution for the problem the author mentions.
Is this because the existence of a solution for that problem is not guaranteed in general?
When existence holds for that problem?
